# Deploying artifacts and dependencies on another system with Maven

Tags: deployment, maven

I am coding a Java program on my development machine. Maven packages this a `myjar.jar`, and I can run it from the command line using `java -cp myjar.jar my.FantasticClass`. It uses library `somelib.jar`. I use Maven, and the project is hosted on github.

When I want to run my project on the target machine, what is the best way to go?

I could package my code as a jar, grab the `somelib.jar` and move it to the target machine manually, but I suppose I could also check out the Maven project from github on the target machine, run it, and have Maven both generate the jar and get the `somelib.jar` file.

Or am I simply overlooking something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution on StackOverflow - use maven-assembly-plugin, and invoke

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

Then I can just run the jar like this:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

Here are the required additions to the POM file. My main class is **demo.GraphTest**

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>demo.GraphTest</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
```